# Activate an HDD in Windows XP (Powershell)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, powershell

After a security patch for Windows XP, all new devices (like hard drives) are disabled by default. I need to activate it automatically.

My idea was to write a Powershell script to activate the drive during boot. Windows 8+ supports commands like `Get-Disk` and `Initialize-Disk`, but these aren't available on my Windows XP machine. Any Ideas?

Comment: You can't run a PowerShell script during boot. Those cmdlets are additions of newer PowerShell versions. I'm not sure whenever recent .NET (4.0) environments are available for WIndows XP or updated PowerShell environments. After all it is EOL. What's the particular reason to use Windows XP?

Comment: We have some 16-bit applications running, which can´t be ported to Win7. Because of that Microsoft still provides patches for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using the Windows devcon tool. ;)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon